# Why is $\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}r^i \leq r^t$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

On page 348 of [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397594901783) by Siegelmann and Sontag, there's a claim that depends on the following inequality:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}r^i \leq r^t$$

(The claim appears after a line consisting only of "Therefore,".  I'm using $r$ for $LW$ in the text.  The same claim can also be found on page 70 of Siegelmann's [book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817639495).)

I don't understand why the inequality must hold.  The only constraint for $r$ implied in the text, as far as I can see, is that it must be non-negative.  I know that the inequality is equivalent to

$$\frac{1-r^t}{1-r} \leq r^t$$

and I have been playing around with algebraic manipulations of this second inequality, but I have not seen how to justify it.  I think there is some simple algebraic trick that I am missing.

Comment: For $t=1$ the inequality is $1\le r$ so clearly there is some other information missing.

Comment: This is clearly wrong for $r<1$, since the LHS is $\geq 1$.

Comment: It's true when $r\ge2$.

Comment: It is valid whenever $r^t (r - 2) + 1 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into the article, the definition of both $L$ and $W$ yields $L> 2$ and $W\ge 1$. Therefore, you should add the assumption $r = LW> 2$.

This directly leads to $r-1>1$ and therefore
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{t-1}r^i = \frac{r^t-1}{r-1} < r^t-1< r^t. $$

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to look at the article and find the relevant assumptions (and then work out the implications of $r>2$).  I had mixed up $W' \in [0,1]$ and $W=W'+1$, which is why I thought that $r$ was merely non-negative.  (Strictly speaking the answer should say "implies" rather than "is equivalent to", since we go from a strict to a non-strict inequality, right?)

Comment: Of course you are right and the "is equivalent to" was an error. I edited the derivation to make it more accessible.

Comment: Ah, thanks--that's very nice simple derivation.  I had verified your claim a different way, but this is better.